# How do I show Knowledge Article content in Community page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, knowledge, napili, lightning-knowledge

I am trying to set up Knowledge in a Community, using the Napili template and the Article Detail page template. I am having trouble getting the page to show just the Article body and not all of the administrative fields in the page layout. I am using the Article Content Component, which is displaying the page layout that is used in the regular Salesforce record page (see the screenshot below).
[image]

How can I get the Component to just show the Article body, or do I need to create a custom component to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cant really change what is and not displayed in the article component. This leaves you with the obvious, which you already stated, Create a custom component (which is pretty straight forward)

Also (Disclaimer-> I work for this company) you can use our [Free AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009x8GjEAI) package to display your knowledge articles with whatever field(s) you want.
[image]
Our [Getting started guide](https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SalesforceV2/Step+1+-+Installing+Coveo+for+Salesforce+Free+Edition) should be more than enough to help you get started =P

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I think you might have linked to the wrong AppExchange package. You said it was free, but the package you linked to says it starts at $1750 per month.

Comment: there is a free version, the Getting started guide goes through the steps. Basically, there are 3 editions, Free/Pro/Enterprise . Free is Free =) However, you are quite right, the Starting At, is a bit missleading and I blame Marketing for that =P

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following CSS to hide the *URL NAME* section entirely:

```
.slds-form div:nth-child(3) {
    display:none;
}
```

And this to remove the field titles specifically:

```
.selfServiceArticleLayout .test-id__field-label {
    display:none;
}
```

Without needing to create anything else.